# Having Multiple Type of Click On RecyclerView Cell elements - Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, click

For having Click listner on a cell in RecyclerView in Xamarin.Android we have a general methode which is :

```
mAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick; // in OnCreate
```

and

```
void OnItemClick (object sender, int position)
        {
            // Display a toast that briefly shows the enumeration of the selected photo:
            int photoNum = position + 1;
            Toast.MakeText(this, "This is photo number " + photoNum, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
```

In ViewHolder we put this code :

```
itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener (base.LayoutPosition);
```

And in  RecyclerView.Adapter we have :

```
public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
```

with :

```
// Raise an event when the item-click takes place:
        void OnClick (int position)
        {
            if (ItemClick != null)
                ItemClick (this, position);
        }
```

Everything works well, BUT IF I want to have more than one type of click on items in ViewHolder, how can I manage this?

For example, I want to define a click on Image which open an activity. And if user click on TextView in the same ViewHolder, it does another action.

```
Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView); 
Image.Click += (sender, e) => listener (base.LayoutPosition); 
Caption = itemView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView); 
Caption.Click += ???
```

Comment: One way is by exposing as many events as you need. `ImageClicked`, `TextViewClicked`, `ItemClicked` etc

Comment: Hi, I have make a demo and post it on the github, you can try it, please feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: @apineda when I have a long list of datas, I load them in packet of 10, and if in third page, I click on item number 3, the click with your method, will call the Item number 3, 13 and 23 etc... I've tried it and because of that, I posted this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an interface to handle this case.

I have post my project on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/RecycleViewScrolling).

### Update:

You can use `View`'s [setTag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) method to store the position.

Comment: Perfect Project, tnx. It works fine BUT!! I need "int position" which user has clicked ! do you have any idea about it? For example in onItemClick(int position)